# Python 3.2 Hangman String edit

Tags: python

This is my code for a school hangman project. I currently have some trouble with editing my `correctguess` string.

I have been told that strings in Python are immutable, but with that fact I now don't know how to add the correctly guessed letter to my guesses. I was originally thinking of using the `find` method, but now I feel like that won't work. If possible, I'd like a solution or a recommendation for creating a string that is editable, or a loop to create new strings. I'd like it so that every time I get a correct guess, (let's say A) my `"HANGMAN"` (which is my code word) would change from `"XXXXXXX"` to `"XAXXXAX"`.

(Sorry that this is hard to explain, the code should be easier to understand, as I added a lot of comments as to what I want to do. I also commented out some code that gave me errors.)

Thanks in advance

```
import sys
message1=("hangman")
l=len(message1)

t = 10
c = 0
tries = str(t)
correct = str(0)


wrongguess=" "

print("Hello, you have 10 tries to achieve the answer.")
for i in range(0,l):
    sys.stdout.write('x')
    i=i+1
print("")

for x in range(0,l):
    message2=input()
    message3= message2.lower()
    finder = message1.find(message3)
    if(int(finder)==-1):
        print("You Fail")
    if(int(finder)!=-1):
        correctguess[int(finder)]=message2
        print(correctguess)


    ## find message 3 within message 1 







## "Find" the input message within the original hangman word; Find the position
## of the "Found" letter within the original message, and replace the "correctguess"
## string's position of the Found letter; The found letter. If not, tries will -1,
## if tries = 0, terminate program

## Create an input loop that will save under a new string. If the input does not equal
## to anything within the original word, add the letter to the "wrongguess" string




##for x in range(0, l-1):
##    message2=input()
##    message3= message2.lower()
##    if message3==message1[x]:
##        correctguess[x]= message3
##        print(correctguess)


##    if message3!=message1[x]:
##        t=t-1
##    if t==0:
##        print("You lose")



##
##if message1==message3:
##    print("Correct! You had " + tries + " tries left, and had " + correct + " correct")
##
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote up a hangman game right now to test, and what worked for me was this:

`word` was the word that the user had to guess.

I had a `mask`, which is a list with the same length as `word`. `mask` consists of only 1s and 0s. If an index of `mask` is 1, then show the user has guessed that letter. If it's 0, the user hasn't guessed it.

Example usage:

```
word = 'hangman'
mask = [0]*len(word)

# How to print the obfuscated word
# Print X if the user hasn't guessed the letter, otherwise print the letter.
print(''.join('X' if mask[i] == 0 else word[i] for i in range(len(mask))))

# How to get the guess
guess = input().strip().lower()[0]

# How to mark the guessed letter in the word
if guess in word:
  mask = [1 if mask[i] == 1 or word[i] == guess else 0 for i in range(len(mask))]
```

Also, I see you iterate through the game with `range(0,l)` where `l = len(word)`. Instead you should use a `while` loop, like so:

```
guessed = False
tries = 10
while (not guessed) and (tries > 0):
  # Play game
```

That way, the game will end if the user guesses correctly, or if the user runs out of tries. After the game, whether the user won or not can be gotten simply by checking the value of `guessed`

Pseudocode:

```
Set the word
init the mask to the length of the word

set tries to the number of guesses the playe rhas
set guessed to False
while not guessed and tries > 0:
  get guess from input
  if guess in word:
    update mask to mark the guessed letters
    if the mask is full of 1s, (if the sum of mask is equal to the length):
      guessed = True
  else:
    tries -= 1
if guessed:
  The user has correctly guessed the word
else:
  The user has failed.
```

Comment: Hello, So I tried your code, and used what you suggested to me. Currently there is a problem with my while loop. After I get everything working as it should, if I place                                                                     
        if guess==word:
        print("Congratulations, you answered correctly")
    
  
    if tries == 0:
        quit()                                                                                                       both in or out of my while loop, they both serve to do nothing.

Comment: you don't need to check `tries` in the loop because that's checked in the while loop. You need to decrement tries at the end of the loop, and check if all letters have been guessed. If it helps, I'll append pseudocode to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to edit a string, you could use a list in conjunction with the string.join method instead. The join method takes a list as an argument and returns a string which is separated by the original string. If you make it an empty string, you'll get the string you need.

```
my_word = ["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"]
''.join(my_word)
# 'HELLO'
my_word[1] = "H"
''.join(my_word)
# 'HHLLO'
```